# Priorities or just setting screen to rotate through touch and not joystick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

Basically I've got a mobile joystick which moves the character and then a swipe touch input to rotate the character and screen but now the joystick is also rotating the character which I don't want to happen, I want to able to move the character with the joystick while also being able to turn him by swiping but I don't want him to turn from using the joystick.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Change your code...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Character Controller script.
In a simple word: Make a boolean variable (like `onJoystick`) and set boolean to true when your joystick is connected. in your Character Controller Script, change the behavior of movements and actions by checking this boolean variable